# Jest: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've created and published my package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/storage-manager-es

So, i can install its in another projects. 
However, i can't test with my package. Because, i get SyntaxError.

import StorageLocal from 'storage-manager-es/src/StorageLocal'

import StorageInterface from './StorageInterface'

^^^^^^

---

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
    }
  }
}
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "storage-manager-es": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^22.1.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For import/export to work you have to tell babel its react app, for that you have to install `npm install babel-preset-react-app --save-dev` and add `"react-app"` in your babel presets. That should work

Comment: It didn't solve

Comment: are you getting this error only in jest test files ?, see if this helps https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1021